# Referencing an interface from ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, interface, instanceof

I am having trouble understanding **((Edible)objects[i]).howToEat()** at line 7 in the java code example given below. Edible is an interface which contains abstract method howToEat() and I understand that this is a reference to an array but how is the "Edible" interface being referenced in this statement?

```
public class TestEdible {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] objects = {new Tiger(), new Chicken(), new Apple()};
        for (int i= 0; i <objects.length; i++) {
            if(objects[i] instanceof Edible) {
                System.out.println( ((Edible)objects[i]).howToEat() );
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Object is not edible");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please explain if the interface is being referenced from an object or array in the statement, or if this is just a syntax related to interfaces that I may not be familiar with. I am not well versed in use of interfaces so I may be overlooking something, thank you.

Comment: Just to make sure, your question is about the syntax of `((Edible)objects[i])`? you're asking what it means here?

Comment: Correct, Igor. How is the Edible interface being referenced in ((Edible)objects[i])?

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of that @user16320675, post has been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((Edible)objects[i])` syntax means *cast `objects[i]` to `Edible`*. It could be just `(Edible)objects[i]`. It's wrapped into brackets just to inline it for the following method call.

So the code

```
if(objects[i] instanceof Edible) {
   System.out.println( ((Edible)objects[i]).howToEat() );
}
```

could be rewritten as simpler to read:

```
if(objects[i] instanceof Edible) {
   Edible currentObject = (Edible) objects[i];
   System.out.println(currentObject.howToEat());
}
```

So you're basically telling the Java compiler that you want to threat `object[i]` as an `Edible` because you know what you do and you already checked it with `instanceof` above.

As @daniu noted, with Java 16 you can have another syntax for that:

```
if(objects[i] instanceof Edible currentObject) {
   System.out.println(currentObject.howToEat());
}
```

Comment: Note that in the newer versions of Java (17), there is the `if objects[i] instanceof Edible e) { System.out.println(e.howToEat()); }` syntax.

Comment: @daniu, Igor it is permanent since Java 16: [JDK 16 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/16-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8250623) (available since [Java 14, 3 years ago] as Preview Feature)

Comment: Ah, thank you. I guess I'm still stuck with Java 11 somehow :(